# Product of convergent sequences in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am looking to prove that the product of two $\{\bf x_n \} \to x $, $\{\bf z_n\} \to z$ sequences in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$ converges to $\{\bf x_n \cdot z_n \} \to x \cdot z $.

I am able to do the particular case of sequences in ${\mathbb{R}}$, but other than substituting the absolute values for the Euclidean norm, I am struggling to move forward. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$

$$|<x_n,y_n>-<x,y>| \leq |<x_n,y_n-y>|+|<x_n-x,y>| $$ $$\leq ||x_n||||y_n-y||+||x_n-x||||y||$$

Since $x_n$ conveeges,it is bounded so exists $M>0$ such that $||x_n|| \leq M,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

So for all $n \geq \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ you have what you want.

Exists $N_1,N_2 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $||x_n-x|| <\frac{\epsilon}{2||y||}$ and $||y_n-y|| <\frac{\epsilon}{2M},\forall n \geq N_2$

$<.,.>$ denotes the inner product.

In the second inequality we used Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more about defining the $\epsilon$ that bounds each $\lVert \bf y_n - y \rVert$. As I see it now, $\lVert \bf y_n - y \rVert < \epsilon/ \lVert \bf x \rVert$, but not sure about how to define that last one expression.

Comment: @econ86 i edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you define it initially with the absolute value of the inner product instead of $\lVert \cdot \rVert$? Would it be wrong to say define $\lVert x_n y_n - xy \rVert \leq \lVert x_n(y_n-y) \rVert + \lVert y(x_n-x) \rVert \leq \lVert x_n \rVert \lVert(y_n-y)\rVert + \lVert y \rVert \lVert (x_n-x) \rVert$?

Comment: because the inner product of two vectors is a real number.. and also the equality in your comment is not true always..so you also need the C-S inequality.

Comment: My bad, there should be a $\leq$ there. Is it then fine now? (simply by $\lVert xy \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert$, no need for C-S?)

Comment: Yes it is..$|x \cdot y| \leq ||x||||y||$  is the Cauchy swartz inequality